# unable to display three.js elements in a scene due to camera position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene with multiple elements, say a cube, cylinder, sphere and some more. I have set the camera position for the scene at (0,30,40) and am trying to display all other elements using this camera position.

However, I observe that in the code below, where I display a simple moving cube, it does not work with the camera positioning I need for the rest of the scene, but works with only another camera configuration.

See lines 30-32 in my javascript code below (I have commented it). Basically it works for camera position (0,-400,400) but does not work for camera position (0,30,40) which I what I need as part of my project settings, to accommodate the rest of the elements.

```
     var angularSpeed = 0.2;
            var lastTime = 0;

            function animate(){
                var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
                var angularChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
                cube.rotation.y -= angularChange;
                lastTime = time;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);

                requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                    animate();
                });
            }

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

            /* Works */
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.y = -400;
            camera.position.z = 400;

            /* Does not work, but I want these to be the camera settings */
//            camera.position.x = 0;
//            camera.position.y = 30;
//            camera.position.z = 40;

            camera.rotation.x = 0.70;

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200,100,100), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());

            scene.add(cube);

            animate();
```

I have created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vusapakino/edit?html,js,output) for the same.

How is this usually done? I know I can also change the position of the cube using it's APIs and by playing around with cube.position.x, cube.position.y and cube.position.z, keeping the camera settings required by the project (0,30,40) in this case, and hope to find some cube position where it gets displayed on screen. But I'm not sure if doing a trial and error on the above three variables is the best way to go about it.

Please advise.

EDIT : I have tried to create a scene which includes the following

```
var cube,cylinder,sphere,plane,polyhedron,torusknot,torus;
```

My objective was to display them at the center of the screen irrespective of the camera position I decided for the entire scene (only one camera position for all elements).

This is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fuvosipiye/edit?html,js,output) where I was able to display multiple elements.
For a different camera positioning (x,y,z), I was able to display them at the center of the page either by either/or both of the following'

1. Changing the size of the elements. For example, changing the length, breadth and height of the cube
2. Changing the y position of the element. For example, cube.position.y

However, though, I was able to get it to work this time, I feel it's helped by the fact that only the position.y needed altering. Had x,y,z all needed change, it would be difficult to come up with the position by trial and error.
Is there another way, this is done?
**Finding it slightly difficult to believe that someone who bases all the elements in his scene based on a particular camera position, only needs to alter one coordinate (in my case, the y coordinate) to adjust to any other camera position.**

About using camera.lookAt(cube.position) which was also suggested
I am apprehensive about using this, because in the same scene, I'm interested in look'ingAt, not just the cube, but also the cylinder,sphere,plane,polyhedron,torusknot,torus;

Comment: why dont you scale down your elements

Comment: @gaitat, thanks gaitat. I spent a few hours trying out few things. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 2):

Make the camera look at the cube position (after the cube added to the scene):

```
camera.lookAt (cube.position);
```

Comment: thanks kovacsv, please see my edit above. I've tried out a few things. As I mention, I'm not sure looking at the cube's position can always be a solution, since I also have other elements in my scene.

Comment: You can use any coordinate in camera.lookAt (eg. camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3 (0,0,0));). I think you should calculate the center of your scene, and look at that position.